# How can I run a coroutine faster than Update() in Unity / c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, coroutine

The problem is that it usually caps itself to the framerate of the game. I believe this is due to yield waiting a frame. So is there any way I can run some code at say 8000 times per second in a coroutine or with something else? Sorry for formatting I am new to stackoverflow, Thanks.

In this code I have a coroutine and I want it to run a few thousand times per second.

```
private IEnumerator SampleRateCoroutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return wait;

        audioSource.GetOutputData(dataOut, 0);

        updateTiming = Mathf.Round(1 / (Time.time - prevCoroutineTime));
        prevCoroutineTime = Time.time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Time.deltaTime` to know how long the previous frame took and use a loop in the coroutine to do whatever at whatever frequency you need.

Comment: Why did you need to run it thousand times?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Give us a more details about your use case. Also keep in mind that running a **LOT** of things in one frame can result in anything from jitter to actual lock-up and frame skips resulting in a poor quality product.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your actual intends: Yes, you can!

You could for example want to still make sure a certain frame-rate and e.g. use a `StopWatch` (there are probably more efficient ways to do the same though) and do something like e.g.

```
private IEnumerator SampleRateCoroutine()
{
    var desiredFrameRate = 1 / 60f; // play around with this

    var desiredMaxMilliseconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(desiredFrameRate * 1000);

    var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        audioSource.GetOutputData(dataOut, 0);

        if(stopWatch.elpasedMilliseconds >= desiredMaxMilliseconds)
        {
            updateTiming = Mathf.Round(1 / (Time.time - prevCoroutineTime));
            prevCoroutineTime = Time.time;
            yield return null;
            stopWatch.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

---

or if you really just want to go by a fixed counter - simply use a fixed counter ;)

```
private IEnumerator SampleRateCoroutine()
{
    var callsPerFrame = 1000;

    while (true)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < callsPerFrame; i++)
        {
            audioSource.GetOutputData(dataOut, 0);
        }

        updateTiming = Mathf.Round(1 / (Time.time - prevCoroutineTime));
        prevCoroutineTime = Time.time;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

---

Or if you want it as you say a certain amount per second you basically just have to convert from calls per frame into calls per second (assuming of course the device is strong enough and frame-rate itself will remain more or less stable during this)

```
private IEnumerator SampleRateCoroutine()
{
    var callsPerSecond = 8000;
    
    while (true)
    {
        var framesPerSecond = 1 / Time.deltaTime;
        var callsPerFrame = callsPerSecond / framesPerSecond;

        for(var i = 0; i < callsPerFrame; i++)
        {
            audioSource.GetOutputData(dataOut, 0);
        }

        updateTiming = Mathf.Round(1 / (Time.time - prevCoroutineTime));
        prevCoroutineTime = Time.time;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

*(Wasn't sure exactly what the purpose of `updateTiming` and `prevCoroutineTime` was exactly)*

Comment: I tried this but it didn't recognize the Stopwatch type. I couldn't find anything about it on Google, could you clarify please.

Comment: @PhotonGamer [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) `I couldn't find anything about it on Google` .. [allow me to doubt this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Stopwatch+csharp) ;)